# Update by query is very slow in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I am trying to copy the data of one field with `object` type to another field with `nested` type, using painless script and `_update_by_query`. It took my Elasticsearch cluster ca. 48 hours to copy over 8.4M worth of data, and I want to speed up this operation.

This is the URL:

```
localhost:9200/myindex/_update_by_query?conflicts=proceed&requests_per_second=50
```

and here is the body:

```
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "script": {
        "inline": "ctx._source.myfield_copy = ctx._source.myfield;"
    }
}
```

Any way to speed up this operation?

Answer (score 3):

By specifying `requests_per_second` you're [throttling](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html#_throttling_update_requests) the operation.

Since the default bath size is 1000, and admitting the write time for 50 records is 100ms (hypothesis, your mileage may vary), we have

```
target_time = 1000 / 50 per second = 20 seconds
wait_time = target_time - write_time = 20 seconds - 0.1 seconds = 19.9 seconds
```

So you're basically waiting 19.9 artificial seconds between each batch, which is probably why it takes so long. Just remove `requests_per_second` altogether and that should already help a lot.

If you're just copying a field into another, another performance improvement  would be to not do it with a script but with an ingest pipeline

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/copy-field
{
  "processors": [
    {
      "set": {
        "field": "myfield_copy",
        "copy_from": "myfield"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And then simply run update by query by referencing that pipeline:

```
POST myindex/_update_by_query?pipeline=copy-field&wait_for_completion=false
```